# Is this notation for a single capacitor or a dual capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, schematics, motor-controller

So Im trying to repair the indoor fan on our ducted AC system (2 weeks wait to get it replaced on warranty). Capacity has exploded. I replaced it with a similar cap (8uF 400v) and wired it the same as per the schematic however the fan still won't start.

Is the capacitor notation on the schematic indicating it is a dual capacitor? Or is it indicating a single capacitor with a junction on one plate? I can't find the datasheet for the original capacitor. Any advice would be great.

If I can't get a dual capacitor, how could I wire up two of these capacitors to have the same affect?

Or is it likely the fan is the problem?

Final question, how can I find the datasheet for the original capacitor?

[image]

Comment: Looks to be a single capacitor. The notation on the left side is common in many of the appliance schematics that I have worked with in the past. You can confirm this - if the capacitor has two fast-on tabs for each terminal.

Comment: Dual caps have different values for Start Run motors.  THis one has only one 8uF 450V Polycap for fan phase shift to secondary pole.  What did you get?

Comment: Check for a blown 5A fuse.  That would do it.

Comment: Yeah I got a 8uF 400v cap as well so it should be identical. Fuse looks ok but I will confirm with a meter.

Comment: Fuses are all good. There are two red LEDs on the board, can't find a service manual anywhere so I'm going to assume the fan it self is seized. The cap gets really hot if you leave it "running" for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dead capacitor is from "Shiny Space Enterprise Co, LTD" you can find specifications from about page 10 their [catalog](http://shinyspace.com/doc/catalog.pdf) or [here](http://shinyspace.com/en/mpp/smpa_ul.aspx). It is a single 8µF motor run capacitor. I suspect the dual terminals are there to make it possible to connect it without having to have two wires go into one terminal.

You say you've checked the fuses. I'd also check the relay's contacts haven't welded, then the cables to the fan for damage or shorts and finally see (with the power isolated) if I could turn the fan by hand.